# Going back two activities without losing top activity

Tags: android, navigation

I have 5 activities A, B, C, D and E ,I want to go back from activity E to activity C without losing activity A and activity B.

I want to keep activity A as top activity and keep all data in activity C, which come from activity A and activity B.

Which flags should I use ?
How to implement going back two activities without losing top activities.

Comment: can u tired for this ?

Comment: from Activity C where can you navigate ? only D or both D and E ?

Comment: From activity D to E , you have to finish the activty , In that case , when you backpress , activty C is avialble.

Comment: Other things may depend on what you are doing  in C, D and E .

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say that in activity E there are two buttons 
one go back to D the other go back to C.

Answer (score 0):

For that you should have to understand whole scenario of [**Android Activity launchMode**](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-activity-launchmode-explained-cbc6cf996802) and set flag programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You want to go from Activity **E** to **C** , you don't want to back Activity **D**

> A -> B -> C -> D -> E

When you are going to D -> E (D to E) finish Activity D. So when you back from E directly you come to Activity C.

**Reference Code :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_D.this, Activity_E.class);
finish();  //Kill the activity from which you will go to next activity 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say that in activity E there are two buttons 
one go back to D the other go back to C.

Answer (score 0):

I Ignore Other things, If you gona go back to C.

Activty D-> Activty E

```
Intent  intent=new Intent(Activty D , Activty E)
startActivty(intent)
finish();
```

On Press Back Button

```
@overide onBackPressed()
{
super.onBackPressed();
yourActivity.this.finish;  //It will remove E from stack if you want
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say that in activity E there are two buttons 
one go back to D the other go back to C.